# Sql server vs MS Access performance

Tags: performance, ms-access, sql-server-2005, oledb

I have an existing application which uses Sql Server 2005 as a back-end. It contains huge records, I need to join tables which contain 50K-70K. Client m/c is a lower hardware.

So, can I improve its performance by using MS Access as a back-end? I also need to search operation on an Access file. So, which one is better for performance?

Querying Access is better than querying SQL in lower h/w?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. Hardware specs would be a start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because SQL Server does run as a separate process, caches results, uses ram and processing power when not being queried, etc., IF the other computer has very little RAM or a very slow processor (or perhaps even more importantly a single-core processor), I could see a situation where SQL Server is actually SLOWER than MS Access use.

Without information about your hardware setup, approximately what percentage of your application relies on querying the database, etc., I'm not sure this question can be easily answered.

MS SQL Server 2005 Express requires at least 512 MB RAM (see http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/system-requirements.aspx), so if your lower-end hardware doesn't have at least 512MB, I would certainly choose MS Access over SQL Server.

I should also add that you may want to consider SQLite (see http://www.sqlite.org/) which should be significantly less overhead than MS SQL Server. I'm not certain how it would stack up against MS Access use over something like Jet. My gut instinct is that it would perform better with less overhead.

Comment: I have checked performance with both Sql and Access with various no of records. Generally ms access runs faster than sql first time. Then after second run for same search criteria sql runs faster and access takes same time every time I run query.

Comment: Agree. When no network and no server and single user then Access (JET) is often significantly faster than sql server. SQL server forces you to do everything though a huge extra layer that involves transactions and a socket based (network) connection. Jet just literally scraps data right off the disk with no huge framework between that reading of data from the disk. SQL server or Access (JET) does not change the speed of file reading from the disk drive. So, JET has significant less overhead then sql server and my testing shows JET is often 50% faster when no network is involved.

Comment: Exactly, I have same environment. I just need to create access database as per sql database /insert record and read them. I had created index on it and I am getting more than 50% faster than SQL server. Without indexing it does not give such a performance. And thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

70,000 records is really not that big for SQL server (or access for that matter). I would echo what has already been said and say that all things being equal SQL server will out perform Access.

I would go back to your query and look at the execution plan to see why it is so slow, maybe missing indexes, out of date statistics or a whole host of other reasons could explain your current performance problems.

SQL server also gives you the option of using materialised views to help with performance. The trade of is slower insert/update/delete performance but if you read more than you write it might be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

I think Albert Kallal's comment is right, and the fact is that if you have a single-user app running on a single workstation (Access client with SQL Server running on the same workstation as a client), it will quite often be slower than if the setup on that workstation were Access client to Jet/ACE back end on the same machine. SQL Server adds a lot of overhead that delivers no benefit when there is no network in between the client and the SQL Server.

The performance equation flips when there's a network involved, even for a single-user app. If the Access client runs on a workstation, and the SQL Server on a server on the other end of a network connection (even a fast one), it will likely be faster than if the data is stored in a Jet/ACE file on a file server.

But it's not a given, in my opinion. It depends entirely on the engineering of the application and the excellence of the schema.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to use SQL Server Express 2005 VS MS Access 2010, many people said SQL Server would run faster than MS Access (I also thought so first). But what happened then made me surprised, run query with MS Access is faster than SQL Server with significant result (with the same data & structure because I'd converted from Access to SQL Server before).

But i don't know its performance in another processes like insert, update, and delete yet.

Answer (score 1):

Local SQL Server Express 2014
1 Minute about 2200 records (2200x connect to DB and retrieve 1 record)

External SQL Server Express 2014 (different IP)
1 Minute about 2200 records (2200x connect to DB and retrieve 1 record)

External SQL Server 2000 (old server)
1 Minute about 10000 records (10000x connect to DB and retrieve 1 record)

Locale Access Database
1 Minute about 55000 records (55000x connect to DB and retrieve 1 record)

We are also surprised.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the question directly, but first it is important to know a few things about Access and SQL.

In general, I have found that a small database with up to 10K records will perform equally well on both Access or SQL if all machines have reasonable hardware. Access has a benefit for simplicity for a small number of users, up to 4, but also has a size limitation of 2GB. So you need to be careful that the database size stays below this limit. Some databases start small, but then have a way of growing over time. Something to keep in mind when planning for the future of your program and/or database. If you are might approach the 2GB the limit, one option is to use Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express edition which has a database size limit of 10GB. SQL Express is full SQL, but with size limitations. Full blown SQL Server 2014 has a max database size of 524PB (524,000,000GB). So it would be fair to say it has no practical limit.

If your database has more than 10K records and especially for larger databases of 100K records or more, SQL can demonstrate significant performance gains.

Some performance with MS Access can be achieved by using "Pass through queries" as can any program that uses SQL optimized queries.

Why? The answer comes from how the technology works under the hood. With Access, if it not using "Pass through queries" it will read an entire table, find which records it needs and then show the result. With a program using SQL optimized queries, the SQL engine returns just the results in a very efficient manner.

At the end of the day, if you have a small (<10K record) database used by up to 4 people, MS Access might make sense. If you have plans that the database could grow to more than 10K records or be used by more than 5 users, SQL would be the logical choice.

Specifically for the question posed about a 50-70K record database. I think if you have reasonable hardware, generally SQL will perform better, if you have a unique situation (such as lower hardware on the SQL server) a move to Access could see some improvements.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this topic is that one should think of payload in terms of pickup truck versus an 18 wheeler.  Better/worse/faster/slower somewhat misses the point.  It is a matter of choosing the appropriate vehicle for the payload.

70k records is easily handled by today's PCs.  So one may as well stick with the pickup truck, unless an organization already has an installed skill set of SQL Servers there would be no reason to use it for an on-premise Windows application of just 70k records. Obviously if it is a web/mobile app that requires a backend db technology then Access isn't a candidate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's other layers control query performance, for instance if you're using a linked server or a VPN that will extremely affect query performance in SQL Server .

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server will always give you better performance because the query is executed on the server.  Access on the back-end won't help because your client application will need to pull all the data from the tables, and then perform the join locally.

Comment: For a high end system, this is certainly a safe assumption. I have certainly seen some setups where the overhead of SQL Server alone is sufficiently taxing on a system that using something like MS Access or XML with something like the Jet Database drivers would be more effective. Low-end systems seems to be the focus of the question at hand.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct for a single machine where the Access client and the SQL Server are running on the same workstation. SQL Server will often (though not always) be faster if it's on a dedicated server that the workstation connects to if you're comparing that to storing the Access data tables on a file server. In other words, the network penalizes the Jet/ACE back end much more than the SQL Server. Both on the same machine, I'd expect the SQL Server to be slower (or no faster) in many cases.

Answer (score -4):

SQL Server has better indexing options... Filtered indexes, included columns, etc
There is ZERO chance that Access query is faster than a properly indexed SQL Server database query.

Comment: I don't know about *zero*. With only 70k records, if the would-be server is underpowered for SQL Server, it's *possible* better performance in certain queries could happen in Access. However, the more likely problem *is definitely* the database/index configuration.

Comment: zero chance. anyone who disagrees doesn't know enough about SQL Server indexing.

Comment: @Aaron Kempf people like you are why I made https://whymicrosoft.fail :) they've created so much dogma in the IT world that us younger developers are now having to muddle through the resultant technical debt woefully. Thank you for your contribution.